# 2sls IV with different unit of observation - Stata

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I am doing some data analysis on Stata on a big sample and it turned out it might be useful to use an IV approach.

My data are on **two levels**: *individuals* and *groups*. The group level is obtained collapsing individual data on their averages by group.

The instrumental variable I want to use is at the individual level and it is not possible to be shifted at the group level. Furthermore it is a categorical variable (later trasformed in a set of dummies variables).

### What I did is:

- to estimate the first step at the individual level (N=130,000)
- to store the fitted values of the variable I am interested in,
- to collapse this variable at the group level (N=3000)
- to estimate the second stage at the group level (the main relation I am interested in)

Reading some econometrics papers I guess what I obtained in the second stage is correct in term of parameters *but not in terms of standard error/ t-statistics*.

Unfortunately I cannot use built-in Stata function as it does not allow to use different sample in the two stages.

My questions are (1) if the procedure above described might be correct and (2) how I may compute correctly the t-statistics in the second stage.

Comment: No need for personal comments at beginning and end of posts. How you came to ask the question and your appreciation of help are not needed and/or taken to be natural.

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not stay at the micro level, and possibly add some groups variables?

Comment: Because what I am interested in are some characteristics at the "group level". If I would consider the "individual level" I would overweight the group containing more individuals, being the group size also considered in the regression at the group level. If I am not clear I will try to give an example